# react router show root component as well as routed path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I currently new to React and trying to use React Router. But I'm having the issue where the top level component is being shown as well as the component in the path. In my App.js I have a Dashboard component which has a NavBar component and has my router on there.

Here is my Dashboard component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { adalApiFetch } from "../config/adal-config";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";

export default class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isData: false,
      data: []
    };
    this.postToBackEnd = this.postToBackEnd.bind(this);
  }

  fetchData = () => {
    adalApiFetch(fetch, "/g2", {})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (!this.isCancelled) {
          this.setState({ isData: true, data: responseJson });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  postToBackEnd() {
    adalApiFetch(fetch, "/sendEmail", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.data.username,
        email: this.state.data.email
      })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log(responseJson);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { data, isData } = this.state;

    let spinner = (
      <strong className="c-spinner" role="progressbar">
        Loading…
      </strong>
    );

    return (
      <div>
          <header>
            <NavBar username={data.username} user_id={data.id} />
          </header>
        {isData ? (
          <div>

            <div className="o-container">
              <p className="c-heading-alpha u-margin-bottom-none">
                Wifi Maintenance Notifications
              </p>
              <p className="c-heading-delta u-margin-bottom"></p>
            </div>
            <div className="o-container">
              <article className="c-tile">
                <div className="c-tile__content">
                  <div className="c-tile__body u-padding-all">
                    <button
                      className="c-btn c-btn--primary"
                      onClick={this.postToBackEnd}>
                      Post
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="o-container">{spinner}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my NavBar component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { logOut } from "../config/adal-config";
import "./styles/NavBar.scss";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  NavLink,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import Account from "./Account";
import History from "./History";


export default class NavBar extends Component {
  onLogOut() {   
    logOut();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="Header-navbar">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <NavLink exact to="/">
                Home
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink exact to="/history">
                History
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink exact  to="/account">
                Account
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink exact to="/logout" onClick={() => this.onLogOut()}>
              logout
              </NavLink>
            </li> 
            <li>{this.props.username}</li>
          </ul>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route  exact path="/history" render={() => <History/>} />
            <Route  exact path="/account" render={() => <Account/>} />
          </Switch>
          <p hidden>{this.props.user_id}</p>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

The History and Account component only have a simple H1 tag. Whenever I navigate to these component my dashboard component is also loaded. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use this to make a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wr2grm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rendering the `NavBar` inside of the `Dashboard` component, that's why you keep seeing that component as well. Try removing the `NavBar` from the `Dashboard` component and use it as your applications entry point.

To further elaborate, remove this part from Dashboard:

```
 return (
      <div>
          /* Remove these lines
           *<header>
           *  <NavBar username={data.username} user_id={data.id} />
           *</header>
           */
        {isData ? (
```

And just render your `Navbar`, like so:

```
render(<NavBar />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Check out this StackBlitz **[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mmyejf)** for an working example.

Comment: This make sense, but Dashboard fetches data on the initial load and passes the data to navbar hence the `this.props.username`

Comment: @ErgunPolat either transfer this logic inside NavBar, which I wouldnt recommend, or wrap NavBar inside another component that has this data retrieval logic, which can then pass the necessary props to the NavBar. This wrapper would then be your new entry point.

Comment: Ok what I have done is moved the fetching of data to the App.js and also added the navbar component to App.js and passed in data as props to navbar and within navbar I pass data to dashboard component